# I have following piece of code to stop media player

Tags: android

While pressing start button it starts playing the mp3 file, but it doesn't stop while pressing Stop button, I have been through few examples but couldn't find the exact solution

```
public Button play;
public Button stop;
 MediaPlayer mp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    play = (Button)findViewById(R.id.played);
    stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stopped);
    play.setOnClickListener(this);
    stop.setOnClickListener(this);
}

public void onClick(View v) </br>
{
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.you);
    if(v==play && !mp.isPlaying()){
        mp.start();
    }
//below part of code executes but doesn't stop the player
    else if (v==stop){
        mp.stop();
        mp.release();               
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Do like this :**

```
public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()) {
        case  R.id.played:
            if(mp==null || !mp.isPlaying()){
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.you);
                mp.start();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.stopped:
            if(mp!=null && mp.isPlaying()){
                mp.stop();  
                mp.release(); 
            }
            break
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: One more question when I remove the part "mp==null" from the if statement of R.id.played the app stops responding but according to logic it should run. Can you please say the reason for the same.

Comment: what is the question due?

Comment: case  R.id.played:
            if(!mp.isPlaying()){
                mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.you);
                mp.start();
            } this code doesn't work it forces app to close.I just want to know the reason for same.

Answer (score 0):

```
   mp = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.you);
```

create returns a new instance every time you call it. So you are invoking `stop()` on an instance of `mp` different from the one upon you called `start()`. You should call create once, in the `onCreate` for instance